# Automatic scoping of input to function

Tags: scoping, localization

I'd like to write a function whose arguments contains symbols that are automatically localized, just like some built-in functions, like Sum.  Even better, I'd like to see the symbols' color change, to remind the user about the localization.

For example, if I wanted to do matrix multiplication in tensor notation,
where the specified index is summed over the specified coordinates, I would use

```
SetAttributes[contractIndices, HoldAll]
contractIndices[expr_, dummyindices_List, coordinates_List] := 
 Module[{result = Hold[expr]},
  Do[result = Sum[result /. {a -> coord}, {coord, coordinates}], {a, 
    dummyindices}];
  ReleaseHold[result]]
```

and expect

```
contractIndices[f[i, j] g[j, k], {j}, {x, y, z}]
```

to return

```
f[i,x] g[x,k] + f[i,y] g[y,k] + f[i,z] g[z,k]
```

even if the symbol j had been given a value previously.

Of course I could simply always enclose this inside a Module[{j},...], but I want a function that automatically localizes, just as Sum does with its dummy variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done quite easily using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) and [`SyntaxInformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html):

```
SetAttributes[contractIndices, HoldAll]
contractIndices[expr_, dummyindices_List, coordinates_List] :=
 Block[
  dummyindices,
  Module[{result = Hold[expr]}, 
   Do[result = Sum[result /. {a -> coord}, {coord, coordinates}], {a, 
     dummyindices}];
   ReleaseHold[result]]
  ]


SyntaxInformation[
   contractIndices] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {___}, {___}}, 
   "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {2, 2}}};

j = 2; (* to demonstrate successful localization *)
contractIndices[f[i, j] g[j, k], {j}, {x, y, z}]
(* f[i, x] g[x, k] + f[i, y] g[y, k] + f[i, z] g[z, k] *)
```

The localization is very close to what you suggested using `Module`, we simply do it inside the function and use `Block`. The reason I use block is that "`Block`-like" localization is what is used for `Sum`, `Table`, etc., so it felt the most natural here.

The highlighting is done using `SyntaxInformation`. The help is a bit vague and your possibilities are quite limited, but luckily `Solve`-type localization gives the correct coloring:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!