# How does one pass an arbitrary expression (or expressions) to a function to later be evaluated?

Tags: function-construction

This isn't my exact use case, but I think the answer will still be applicable to what I'm doing. I essentially want to create a function with which I can pass an expression (or list thereof), certain symbols that I wish to be local to the function, and some incidentals. A call may look something like `myFunc[{x^2+y/7,8x+4},{x,y},{{1,2},{3,4}}]`.

The function would then return several values obtained by using different numbers for `x` and `y` in each of the expressions. In this case, say `{{1+2/7,12},{9+4/7,28}}` (each of the expressions evaluated with each of the `x`/`y` value pairs from the last argument.

Now, of course I can figure out a lot of this easily, but the part I'm stumped on is how to pass and later use the expressions/symbols. I feel like this has to be possible because native functions like `Plot` do something similar to this (say `Plot[x^2,{x,1,100}]`) where the `x`s turn teal (I assume indicating that they're local or linked or something of the sort).

I've looked all over the Mathematica documentation and just cannot figure out how to do this. I have to think that I just don't know the right terminology to use in looking for the correct method. The most I've gotten is that I may need to set the function to `HoldAllComplete` and use `Block` within the function, but my few attempts at using those for this purpose have been fruitless.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic scoping of input to function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276553/automatic-scoping-of-input-to-function)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thank you. I guess I was just not using the correct terminology when investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this by using the attribute "HoldAll" an your function. This will feed the unevaluated arguments to the function. However, inside the function you need to take care to prevent accidental evaluations.

To make the variables local, we replace the variables with new symbols. Then we use "MapThread" to evaluate the localized expression with the different data:

```
SetAttributes[myfun, HoldAll];
myfun[ex_, vars0_, vals_] := 
 Module[{vars = Table[Unique[], Length@Unevaluated[{x, y}]], local},
  local = 
   Unevaluated[ex] /. Thread[HoldPattern /@ Unevaluated@vars0 -> vars];
  MapThread[local /. (Thread[vars -> {##}]) &, vals]
  ]
```

To test, we may give x and y some values and see if this changes the output:

```
Clear[x,y];
myfun[{x^2 + y/7, 8 x + 4} , {x, y}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
(* {{10/7, 12}, {32/7, 20}} *)

x=10;y=20;
myfun[{x^2 + y/7, 8 x + 4} , {x, y}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
(* {{10/7, 12}, {32/7, 20}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps looking for a combination of [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)?

For example, your toy-example would look like this:

```mathematica
Function[{x, y}, {x^2 + y/7, 8 x + 4}] @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

The `@@@` part stands for [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at the first level (or more recently in 13.1, this is also called [`MapApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html)), and will effectively map the Function over a list of arguments.

It is often convenient to write this as a pure function, like so:

```mathematica
{#1^2 + #2/7, 8 #1 + 4} & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

where #1 and #2 are "formal" [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)s, but note you can also use named parameters if you prefer, using the `#name` syntax.

Comment: This is similar to what I'm looking for, but what I wasn't clear on was how to not evaluate the expression arguments when implementing in a "normal" function.